# Picking Artifact Dynamically From Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pipeline

I have a bash script , in which I written some curl commands to pick the artifact from drop folder and deploy. command is similar like below

```
curl -u uname:password -F file=@"_path/of/project/all-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip" -F name="test-mname"    -F force=true -F install=true http://xx.xx.xxx.xx
```

Here 1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip is dynamic and will change per every release. How can I modify the script so can avoid change in pipeline after every release.

Thanks

Comment: from where the zip file coming from?

Comment: Thats under the drop folder _Alias_Of_Pipeline/drop/artifactxxx.zip

Comment: _Alias_Of_Pipeline/drop/all-1.0.1-SNAPSHOT.zip

Comment: Who determine the `1.0.1`?

Comment: Thats the version in pom.xml which gets updated after each release

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk, do you have any input on that? how version from pom.xml we can pass to curl script.?

Comment: you can read the pom.xml, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56001645/read-version-of-project-in-yaml-file-from-pom-xml-in-azure-pipelines/56004685#56004685

Answer (score 0):

We had only one artifact under drop folder, below script worked for us

```
drop_location="_OurProjetc_PipeLine _Alias\drop"

# Find the most recent file in the drop location
latest_file=$(ls -t "$drop_location" | grep '^test-name' | head -n1)

curl -u uname:passord -F file=@"$drop_location\\$latest_file" -F name="test-name"  -F force=true -F install=true http://xx.xx.xxx.xx
```